# Web Hosting & Domain Listing

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, hosting

I have an account on Dreamhost with a domain name. I have a different account on Dreamhost with hosting.

I'm struggling to find information on how to host the domain on the first account using the second account's hosting package.

I know it can be done through separate companies, however, I have never tried to do this before; any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to point your domain to their name server. If you unsure about it, then you can contact their support team. They will help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve what I require, annoyingly.

However, the agent suggested that I simply remove the registration from the first account and add it to the other; problem with this method is after the site has been launched, the client will require further setup to re-instate the domain on their cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

take the Dns Server IP and all IPs From the Second account because you will refer to those IP adresses when you are creating the domain name on the other Account ..and Copy/Past as it will be shown on one of creating domain steps...

Comment: I get this error "You can't add that domain: already in our system" before I'm able to, since the domain exists within the dreamhost already

Answer (score 0):

Just Point the nameserver(s) for the domain in the account1 with the nameserver(s) of your hosting account in account2 .

for instance if your account2 hosting package name server is

> ns1.dreamhost.com
>
> ns2.dreamhost.com

Login in to your account 1 dns settings of your domain name and enter that nameserver(s) here.That's it

Hope this answers your query !